# Wrap the output from the scripts to the script they runned by into log

Tags: batch-file

I got script that run some scripts from destination path.

I want the echo commands within the scripts will be wrapped by this script, and print it into file.
what I did is:

```
@echo off
> C:\THE_PATH_OF_THE_LOG_FILE(
FORFILES /S /P "C:\THE_SCRIPTS_I_WANT_TO_RUN" /M *.bat /C "cmd /C start call @file"
```

The log file should contain the script's output, but it turned out empty.

Comment: shouldn't there be a closing parathese at the end and `*cmd` be `"cmd` ?

Comment: didn't copy it right from the work computer. I edited it now. thanks for your comment

Comment: insert a space in front of `(` (and delete the file `C:\THE_PATH_OF_THE_LOG_FILE(`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FORFILES /s /P "C:\windows" /M *.bat /C "cmd /C @file >> c:\test.txt"
```

`Start` and `call` change default behaviour. The normal behaviour is just to type the filename. See `start /?` for help on using start and not using start. Call is for calling batch files and has a specific reason for using it. See `call /?`.